# Sum of the Chern number of all bands

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

My understanding is that, if we sum the Chern numbers of all the bands in systems, they add up to zero. I believe this is a rigorous mathematical result. Is it possible to understand this physically?

Comment: Physically: if you have a completely filled band, you can't have a hall conductance. You can't have ANY conductance, but in particular no hall conductance.

Comment: It is indeed a rigorous mathematical result. The Chern number of a band can most conveniently be expressed in terms of the projection $P_n$ onto that band (e.g. see eq-n (3) here https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.51.51). Then we know that the Chern number is additive, so $\sum_n Chern(P_n) = Chern(\sum_n P_n)$. But $\sum_n P_n = 1$, the identity operator, and it is clear from the Berry curvature formula that $Chern(1) = 0$.

Comment: @JahanClaes: but the IQHE works by having completely filled band, and the Hall conductance is associated with those completely filled bands. It is indeed true that with full bands you can't have _longitudinal_ conductance, but AFAIK not so for transversal (i.e. Hall) conductance.

Comment: @PPR Sorry, I meant "completely filled bands," not "A completely filled band." If you have all your bands filled, you are an inert insulator.

Answer (score 1):

The statement that the sum of all Chern numbers vanishes can be made even stronger. Namely, the total Berry curvature over all bands vanishes. The Berry curvature for a band $n$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
F_n(k_x,k_y) = i \left[ \left< \partial_{k_x} u_n \right | \partial_{k_y} u_n \rangle - \left< \partial_{k_y} u_n \right | \partial_{k_x} u_n \rangle \right].
\end{equation}
Inserting the identity operator $1=\sum_m \left| u_m \right> \left< u_m \right|$ (which holds at any momentum) yields
\begin{align}
F_n(k_x,k_y) & = i \sum_m \langle \partial_{k_x} u_n \left | u_m \right> \left< u_m \right| \partial_{k_y} u_n \rangle - i \langle \partial_{k_y} u_n \left| \partial_{k_x} u_n \right> \\
& = i \sum_m \langle \partial_{k_y} u_m \left | u_n \right> \left< u_n \right| \partial_{k_x} u_m \rangle - i \langle \partial_{k_y} u_n \left| \partial_{k_x} u_n \right>,
\end{align}
where in the last step we used
\begin{equation}
0 = \partial_{k_j} \left( \left< u_n \right| u_m \rangle \right) = \left< \partial_{k_j} u_n \right| u_m \rangle + \left< u_n \right| \partial_{k_j} u_m \rangle.
\end{equation}
Hence, the total Berry curvature summed over all bands vanishes:
\begin{align}
\sum_n F_n(k_x,k_y) & = i \sum_{m,n} \langle \partial_{k_y} u_m \left | u_n \right> \left< u_n \right| \partial_{k_x} u_m \rangle - i \sum_n \langle \partial_{k_y} u_n \left| \partial_{k_x} u_n \right> \\
& = i \sum_m \langle \partial_{k_y} u_m \left| \partial_{k_x} u_m \right> - i \sum_n \langle \partial_{k_y} u_n \left| \partial_{k_x} u_n \right> \\
& = 0,
\end{align}
since both sums run over all bands and where we used the completeness relation again in the second step. It follows that the sum of all Chern numbers vanishes:
\begin{equation}
\sum_n \mathcal C_n = \sum_n \int d^2k \, F_n(k_x,k_y) = \int d^2k \sum_n  F_n(k_x,k_y) = 0.
\end{equation}